# After the migration from Asp net core 2.2 to 3.0,I am seeing a 404 Not found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my web api solution, after the migration from Asp net core 2.2 to 3.0, I have changed the code in my startup as below:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    return app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapControllerRoute("test", "storage/I{controller}/{action}", null, null);
    });
}
```

When I hit my endpoints via the tests, I am seeing a 404 Not found.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you define your end points, you may need to add `routes.MapControllers();`

```cs
app.UseRouting();
return app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
{
    routes.MapControllerRoute("test", "storage/I{controller}/{action}", null, null);
    routes.MapControllers();
});
```

Comment: Adding routes.MapControllers did not work for me. Can you elaborate a little more about what you meany by depends on the endpoints?

Comment: I meant if you have [Route("api-path")] or [HttpPost("action-name")] inside the controller, you have to add routes.MapControllers(); line

Comment: Maybe also take a look on this: https://aregcode.com/blog/2019/dotnetcore-understanding-aspnet-endpoint-routing/

Answer (score 0):

if you used identity so, you need to add like below in `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

and also you must add like below to Configure instead of what you used:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to solution to open Folder in File Explorer select path and set Cmd and enter
write in cmd
dotnet ef migrations add init_db
dotnet ef database update
it will work